# Select text between > and <

Tags: jquery

I would like to copy/paste the text which is between `>` and `<` into a textarea or in a `div`. For example, if I have

```
<div><p><div id='1'> Hello my name is </div></p></div>
<div><p><li> Mathieu </div></li></div>
```

and I click on the `div ID=1` (DIVs will not have a class or an ID, this is just for the example) I want to select `Hello my name is` and auto copy/paste into a `textarea`. But it could be everything like `ul`, `li`, `p`, `div` etc. I just want to select text between `>` and `<` when I click on it.

I have this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).bind("mouseup", function() {
            var sel = $.selection('html');
            if (sel != '') {
                $('#yourTextAreaId').val(sel);
                $('#yourDivId').html(sel); // to fill the selection into the body of <div id="yourDivId"></div>
                // send the `sel` here
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: You *don't* want to get the text between `>` and `<`.  What you want to do is parse the HTML and get the value of certain elements.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g3Cwy/

Comment: @adeneo. Thank you so much ! Can it be delimited in a DIV ? I mean, I don't want to do that for all my website but maybe just a big part.

Comment: Sure, just change "document" to something else, like a classname of the containers you'd like to use it on. The click propogates, so you only need to attach the event handler to a container, not all the elements.

Comment: Hi @adeneo, When I click in a "blank" part, it's showing  all my code like style etc. Is it possible de display only the text we visualy see ?

Answer (score 1):

For this example, I'll just use the elements that you referenced in the question, but you probably need to specify all the ones that you want this to apply to.

```
$(function () { //shorthand for document ready
    $("ul, li, p, div").click(function () { //shorthand for click event
        if($(this).text() != "") {
            $("#yourTextAreaId").val($(this).text());
            $("#yourDivId").text($(this).text());
        }
    });    
});
```